# Conditions for $α_{i} <β_{i}$ such that independent $Uniform(α_{i}, β_{i})$ variables $X_{i}$ converge to 0 in distribution and almost surely

Tags: probability

What are the necessary conditions for $α_{i} <β_{i}$ such that independent $Uniform(α_{i}, β_{i})$ variables $X_{i}$

1) converge to $0$ in distribution

2) converge to $0$ almost surely

The $Uniform(α_{i}, β_{i})$ variables $X_{i}$ are not identically distributed.

Comment: @NCh I've attempted to use the definitions of convergence but I didn't really get anywhere.

Comment: Well, how do you think: in the case $\alpha_i=2i$, $\beta_i=3i$, does any of the desired convergences hold?

Comment: For 1, don't we need to consider the value of $F_{X_{i}}$ as i goes to infinity? We want that to be equal to 1 right?

Comment: For positive argument - yes. In order to have $X_i\to 0$ in distribution one need that $F_{X_i}(x)\to F_0(x)$, $x\neq 0$. The function $F_0(x)$ is equal to $1$ for $x>0$ and to $0$ for $x<0$. Does it hold for the case that I proposed above or not?

Comment: If $αi=2i$, $βi=3i$ then we have $F_{X_{i}}(x) = (x-2i)/i$ which as i goes to infinity it will be -2? As long as x is between 2i and 3i

Comment: The probability is a number in the range $[0,1]$. The CDF is a probability. Can the limit of any probabilities be $-2$? Use graphics: plot on a piece of paper  graphics of $F_{X_i}(x)$ for some succesfull $i$ (not only for the values $2i<x<3i$, but for any $x$). Choose some fixed $x$ and follow the dynamisc of $F_{X_i}(x)$.

Comment: @NCh I have attempted to do as you said, but I am still getting no where with this problem. I understand the probability cannot be -2. For fixed x how do we get this limit to go to 1?

Comment: I did not say that this limit should be as required. I just want you to put your own efforts to this simple case and after that draw a conclusion for your task.